# Samba 4.1 (Ubuntu 14.04) prompts for password when listing shares

Tags: ubuntu, samba, ubuntu-14.04, samba4

I had to upgrade my Ubuntu Server to 14.04 which comes with Samba 4.1 (I used Samba 3 previously). I had to switch from security = share to security = user, because it looks like the first one seems to be not supported anymore. And after some struggle I finally got it working, however there is still one issue.

When I enter my \\[server IP] to Windows Explorer I receive prompt for Network Credentials. I need to type **ANY** username and it passes access. The same happens while I'm directly connecting to share and typing any username also helps.

Is it possible to configure the server, so that it doesn't prompt for credentials? Or maybe it's expected behavior with security = user? Or maybe some Widows issue?

No errors are present in log.smbd or log.nmbd.

This is my **testparm** output:

```
[global]
    netbios name = MY_SERVER
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    map to guest = Bad User
    dns proxy = No
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[repository]
    path = /home/repo/repository
    force user = repo
    force group = repo
    read only = No
    create mask = 0644
    guest ok = Yes

[tools]
    path = /home/repo/tools
    force user = repo
    force group = repo
    read only = No
    create mask = 0644
    guest ok = Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `guest ok`, then you have to make sure that the Samba guest account on your Linux does actually have full access to the respective shares.

From the Samba manual on `guest account`:

> This is a username which will be used for access to services which are specified as guest ok (see below). Whatever privileges this user has will be available to any client connecting to the guest service. This user must exist in the password file, but does not require a valid login.

If you are not sure about the standard guest account, just define it here yourself.

Also check out the [Samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Public_Samba_Server) on anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
security = user
```

in the `[global]` section.

Comment: security = user must be default in Samba 4.1 because testparm doesn't output this param. However, I have it in my smb.conf